# How to configure Prettier to add line breaks after if, else if, and else without curly braces?

Tags: javascript, prettier

I'm using Prettier to format my JavaScript code, and I've encountered a formatting issue with how `if/else if/else` statements are being handled when curly braces are not used. Currently, Prettier formats the code like this:

```
if (condition) console.log('1');
else if (otherCondition) console.log('2');
else console.log('3');
```

However, I'd like Prettier to add a line break after each if, else if, and else statement, like this:

```
if (condition)
  console.log('1');
else if (otherCondition)
  console.log('2');
else
  console.log('2');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prettier is probably the wrong tool for the job. Prettier is marketed as being *opinionated* with *very* limited configuration options. The design idea behind it that there should be essentially no decision making about about formatting.

However, in practice I found that gets in the way a lot more often than it helps. What is supposed to be minor changes end up with big differences just because a new constraint was breached and now what is multiple lines of code is collapsed into one or vice versa - one line suddenly formatted as multiple. Often over a simple rename.

If control over the formatting is needed, then [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) can serve for that *and* also check for problems.

[The formatting rules in ESLint] are almost all auto-fixable, which would alleviate most formatting issues. Furthermore, they can be as set as strict or as lax individually for far more control and less formatting disruptions.

In particular the rule that governs for single-line `if` statements (and other single-line control statements) is [`nonblock-statement-body-position`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/nonblock-statement-body-position). With `nonblock-statement-body-position: ["error", "beside"]`:

```js
//incorrect
if (condition) console.log('1');
else if (otherCondition) console.log('2');
else console.log('3');

//correct
if (condition) 
    console.log('1');
else if (otherCondition) 
    console.log('2');
else 
    console.log('3');
```

[See demo](https://eslint.org/play/#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)

Or if some control statements would require the block below, others besides, there is an `overrides` configuration.

For example, `if` (and other) statements should have the body below, however `while` statements should have it beside:

```
//incorrect
if (condition) console.log('1');
else if (otherCondition) console.log('2');
else console.log('3');

while(line = readLine(file)) 
  console.log(line);

//correct
if (condition) 
    console.log('1');
else if (otherCondition) 
    console.log('2');
else 
    console.log('3');

while(line = readLine(file)) console.log(line);
```

[See demo](https://eslint.org/play/#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)